# Emacs - I cannot save buffer into file because of backup

Tags: emacs

I am using <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> to save a change in a buffer to a file. I am getting the following in my minibuffer:

```
symbol's variable as value is void: “/home/alex/\.emacs_backups/”
```

I added `.emacs_backups/` a couple of days ago and I altered my `.emacs` file to:

```
;; create a backup file directory
(defun make-backup-file-name (file)
(concat “/home/alex/.emacs_backups/” (file-name-nondirectory file) “~”))
```

This does not happen in every directory. In some directories I can save a buffer change to a file no problem.

Comment: This has occurred all of a sudden. I have saved many buffer changes to files over the last couple of days.

Comment: I have un-installed and re-installed emacs23 to no avail.

Comment: Just read and understand my answer. There's nothing wrong with your emacs installation, you just have incorrect code in your .emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You have "smart quotes" in your `.emacs`. Elisp uses ASCII doublequotes as string delimiters:

```
(defun make-backup-file-name (file)
    (concat "/home/alex/.emacs_backups/" (file-name-nondirectory file) "~"))
```

I replaced `“` and `”` with `"`

After you edit your `.emacs`, you should evaluate this new function definition with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>, so that you'll be able to save it without getting an error.

Comment: It is the same as mine apart from the indenting.

Comment: Note I am using emacs23.

Comment: No it's not the same as yours. Can't you see the difference between the quotes? Smart quotes are curly, double quotes are straight vertical.

Comment: The same problem occurs also when I try to save my .emacs.

Comment: Yes I see. My apologies.

Comment: You need to evaluate the corrected definition so that you can save. Or edit your .emacs using a different editor.

Comment: O.K. that seems to have done it. Thank you Barmar. Do you have any idea why this problem occurred so suddenly? It was not a problem before.

Comment: It occurred when you added that function and restarted Emacs, because your function was using incorrect Lisp syntax.

Comment: Starting Emacs from the command line as `emacs -Q` is useful if you need to make an emergency edit to a broken init file like this.  The `-Q` bypasses most customization files.